# How to remove an element using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, sax

Thanks for previous replies,

I am new to parsing concept using java, can anyone guide me how to modify the xml using saxparser. i searched long time to delete the tag but i dont know how to delete. pls guide me

Comment: Please explain what do you mean. You cannot delete element using SAX parser as SAX parser produces events for each element. You can handle particular event or just ignore it but not delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove an element using this :

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
reader.setEncoding(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
Document customXmlDocument = reader.read(inputStream);
// Get the element you want to remove and then pass it to the remove method as so
customXmlDocument.remove(Element)
```